# htaccess - deny directory based on geolocation

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, geoip

I am setting up a WordPress site in a subdomain. The subdomain will be in a subdirectory of the main directory.

So http://dl.abc.com will be in the folder /public_html/dl/

Within there is going to be the wp-admin folder when WordPress is installed:
/public_html/dl/wp-admin/

That wp-admin folder we wanted to block anyone trying to access it (or any files/subdirectories contained within) except those users from Australia and Singapore.

**Is this the correct way to go about it?** (I suspect a caveat is any plugins that make ajax requests by calling admin-ajax.php won't work properly?)

```
<ifModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On
# Put countries to allow here
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NZ AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SG AllowCountry
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
</ifModule>
```

**Second question is how can we go about doing the same thing with the wp-login.php file that will be installed within the /public_html/dl/ folder?** 
Will this work if we put it in the .htaccess file within the /public_html/dl/ directory? Or is there a better way?

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
<ifModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On
# Put countries to allow here
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NZ AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SG AllowCountry
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
</ifModule>
</Files>
```

?

And lastly, I'd like to have a bit of additional "security through obscurity" in that for both examples above **I'd rather return the "404 not found" error instead of the denied error. 
What's the best way to do that?**

Unfortunately we don't have any sort of dev/test server to try things out with first, so want to get this as close to perfect as possible the first time through.

Thank you.
_

Answer (score 1):

**htaccess - deny directory based on geolocation** 
check this url :https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: I looked at the link. I don't see anything there that's more specific around GeoLocations and File filters. It also doesn't clearly explain if I can/should put a `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` inside the `<IfModule>` with the GeoLocation info.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your second question**, according to this page:
https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess/
you can surround other directives with the `<Files></Files>` or `<FilesMatch></FilesMatch>` directive:

> "The  directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by
>   filename. It should be matched with a  directive. The
>   directives given within this section will be applied to any object
>   with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified
>   filename.  sections are processed in the order they appear in
>   the configuration file, after the  sections and .htaccess
>   files are read, but before  sections. Note that  can
>   be nested inside  sections to restrict the portion of the
>   filesystem they apply to."

So essentially it seems that what you have stated already *should* work.